# is there an error sending data from typescript (front-end) to Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to post data obtained from a form to my database.

In Frontend side i am using Typescript and i was trying to send data to Backend side through 'headers' because in another method this type of assigment works properly but, in this case in backend side i get an undefined value all the time.

Form:

[image]

I am gonna show my code:

```
export class PacienteService
{
  private myAppUrl: string;
  private myApiUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)
  {
    this.myAppUrl = environments.endpoint;
    this.myApiUrl = 'api/pacientes'
  }

  postPaciente(paciente: Paciente)
  {

    console.log(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}/`);
    console.log('Rut: ' + paciente.rut);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}/`, {headers: {'rut': rut}})

}
```

first console.log() at postPaciente retrieve correctly url i need: http://localhost/api/pacientes/
Second console.log() also works properly, any value i write appear here.

[image]

http.post is connected with backend side:

```
export const postPaciente = (req: Request, res: Response) => 
{
    const { rut } = req.headers
        console.log('En postPaciente:');
        res.status(200).send('Rut:' + rut);
        console.log('Rut: ' + rut);
}
```

How it is connected to that?

```
constructor()
    {
        this.app = express();
    }
routes()
    {
        this.app.use('/api/medicos', enrutador);
        this.app.use('/api/pacientes', routerPacientes)
        
    }
```

routerPacientes

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { postPaciente } from "../controllers/pacientes.controllers";

const router = Router();

router.post('/', postPaciente);


export default router;
```

Using Postman i have not any problem:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Backend side receive correctly data from Postman but not from my Frontend side.

Comment: Please share details about "in backend side i get an undefined value all the time."

Comment: i edited my question. i hope it helps

Comment: I see this: `headers: {'rut': rut}`   and it is complaining about `Rut`  (notice the capital letter R

Comment: Your `console.log` on the client side outputs `paciente.rut` , but to your headers, you only add `{headers: {'rut': rut}}` ... So probably the headers won't contain a value for `rut` ... Check the developer tools in the browser if the header value is set correctly

Comment: @Luuk `Rut` only comes from `console.log("Rut", ...)` all code other code uses `rut`

Comment: @derpirscher: second to last picture, shows `rut` in headers, and `Rut` in body. I would make sure it's always the same..., and last picture shows `Rut: undefined`.

Comment: any string's ```rut``` i wrote i changed to ```Rut``` now but i must say that paciente.rut is the value i send because ```paciente``` appears from an interface ```Paciente``` and it receive the data i wrote on the form before

Comment: @Luuk  thats the result from the working postman request, the capital `Rut` is just from `res.status(200).send('Rut:' + rut);` Every reference to an actual variable is done as `rut`  and the error is clearly at creating the headers for the request, where OP uses an undefined variable instead of a property of the known object

Comment: @JoaquinIbañezLopez lowercase `rut` was fine, because everywhere you accessed an acutal value you did it with lowercase `rut`.  The problem is as I commented above, when you set your headers in the `http.post....` you do `{headers: { "rut": rut}}` but there is no variable `rut` there only `paciente.rut` (which you use in the `console.log`). Thus, the headers sent by your webclient, won't contain a value for `rut`. Use `{headers: { "rut": paciente.rut}}` instead and it will work

Comment: I see my error. I changed to ```this.http.post<any>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}/`, {headers: {'Rut': paciente.rut}})``` but, sadly, i still getting undefined value

Comment: Well, now after you changed that `rut` to `Rut`, make sure, you changed every instance on the back- and frontend to the correct casing ...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at last

I made a change in the frontend.

```js
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}/`, {headers: {'rut': rut}})
```

to

```js
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}/`, {'rut': rut})
```

On the backend:

From:

```js
const { rut } = req.headers
```

to

```js
const { rut } = req.body
```

The `headers` function works correctly when I use the `get` method, but it doesn't work with the `post` method.